# Canonical. Two methods at the same time?

Tags: canonical-url

I have a blog. I am considering to post also on LinkedIn, the same text. My blog is for me the most important. If I understand I can:

- Put a link in the head of my blog:

  `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.link-to-the-same-page/" />`
- In the post of LinkedIn I can put a link to the post in my blog:

  `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.link-to-the-original-post/" />`

My question is, should I use both methods or only one?

Comment: Are you sure you can add canonical tags (or other meta tags) to LinkedIn articles? I don't believe they offer that functionality. Canonical tags live in the head of doc, and should only be on the content you want to see in SERPs specifically. Look into your LinkedIn Article settings; you should be able to restrict LI articles to just that ecosystem. Then you'll have your website in SERPs and LI on the platform. "If Posts & Activities is not checked in the Public Profile section, then your articles won't be accessible by members who aren't logged into LinkedIn" and thus they won't be in SERPs.

Answer (score 2):

If your blog is important for you then it may not be recommended to do what you are intending to do.

Google supports cross domain canonical but probably it's not recommended in your situation. If you still need to use then the best approach would be to have original content on LinkedIn and in your website you can place canonical to LinkedIn as you got full content on your website. Learn more: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html

The way it appears, you would like to market your content.

If you are serious about producing quality content then just market your content on different platforms.

To market your content you may consider following:

- Share your content on social media platforms.
- LinkedIn: You can do a short post with a button to go to your blog.
- To have better authority, you may consider having occasional unique content in your LinkedIn profile.

Comment: If the OP posts to LinkedIn, then the content will in effect belong to and benefit LinkedIn. Bad idea! The OP should always post to his/her site then perhaps a teaser on LinkedIn with a link back to the site. People should not be so eager to give their work away.

Comment: Today I have read a post of Reid Hoffman, founder of LinkedIn.  It is the exact same content, not a teaser, in LinkedIn and in Medium.

Comment: OP LinkedIn: As you can read I have not recommended either step. If still needed to use then ORIGINAL content on LinkedIn (Intentionally, knowing it will benefit Linkedin post) as placing canonical on the website would be lot easier. Meaning not recommending as a solution to the problem but using canonical properly. If you read through in detail i have said if serious about own blog then don't worry about either step build content on the website and have a very little post on LinkedIn with a backlink going to blog post.